# How to solve error gdk-05030 when importing csv data in SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, date, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a problem importing a CSV file using SQL Developer. I created a table to import a 'date' data by using the code below

```
CREATE TABLE DEPARTMENT (
  DATECOLUMN DATE
);
```

I imported the CSV by right clicking and so on.

Interestingly, the CSV 'date' data has a format of 'YYYY-MM-DD', but when loaded in SQL developer (preview, before importing), it took the format of 'MM/DD/YYYY'.

I believe this is the problem, because when trying to import, it returned error "gdk-05030", meaning the data contains more than needed (to fit the format).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me, it looks as follows:

- date format in a CSV file is `yyyy-mm-dd` (as you said)
- when you queried the table after insert, you found out that values look differently - `mm/dd/yyyy`
- it is because **current settings** use that date format. If you want to change it, run

  ```
  alter session set nls_date_format = 'yyyy-mm-dd';
  ```

  and then select rows from the table.
- alternatively, go to SQL Developer's Preferences, and set desired date format in its [Database - NLS] section.

Comment: Sorry, my explanation might have been poor. The mm/dd/yyyy format is shown Before inserting(the preview). not the queried result.

Comment: Did you try with ALTER SESSION?

Comment: My words were poor. Your code made a change to settings, yes.

Comment: So ... is it now fixed?

Comment: Nope. If you see my first comment(edited), either I need to run a different code, or the format wasn't the problem in the first place. If still willing to help, I could edit my post to give you more information?

Comment: Sure; column's datatype is DATE, so ALTER SESSION or NLS settings *should* make a difference. Maybe you could attach a screenshot which illustrates what's going on.

Comment: Edited the post, but I am convinced the problem isn't the format. I think it's something much more simple, elementry, as I'm just a noob.

Comment: The 2nd screenshot shows loading process; disregard that. Finish the loading, and then - in SQL Worksheet - run `select * from that_table` - what is date format now?

Comment: Basically, you can't affect how date is *stored* into DATE datatype column - Oracle uses its internal format. We just "present" date values in format we find appropriate, either by altering the session or using TO_CHAR function.

Comment: Ah, so changing the csv file format is impossible, if I understand correctly. The result returns nothing, as while importing, it spits out error gdk-05030. The screenshot is on the post.

Comment: Exactly; you can't modify CSV file's contents, SQL Developer isn't a "file editor" :) It looks as if not all data in MGRSTARTDATE column follow the same format. Rows screenshot shows *look* the same, so - could you create a small copy of the original CSV files and try to load only those 7 rows that looks OK? If it works OK, then you should find the culprit in the CSV file. **Alternatively**, modify table column's datatype to e.g. VARCHAR2(20) and load the whole file. Then, using SQL, find invalid values and fix them (and later copy valid values into a DATE datatype column).

Comment: It worked. Thank you for all the answers. I've yet checked the format of all the rows, but importing it to varchar2 worked, and thats about all I need, as I wouldn't be modifiying the datas so much. Thanks!